# É possível relacionar 2 tabelas de 2 bancos diferentes?

Tags: banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados, relacionamento

Estou querendo relacionar 2 tabelas de bancos diferentes. Estou utilizando SQL Server SSMS 17.9.1.

TBL1 no DB1
TBL2 no DB2

Cenários:

1. Os dois bancos estão no mesmo servidor;
2. O banco de dados 1 esta no meu servidor e o banco de dados 2 está em um servidor externo.

Teria alguma saída para atender os dois cenários? Pois inicialmente os dois bancos ficarão no mesmo servidor, porém posteriormente o BD 2 pode ir para outro servidor.

Comment: Sim, com `SELECT` é possível sim. E se os dois bancos estiverem em servidores diferentes, porém se comunicam entre si, também é possível.

Comment: como eu faria esse SELECT com um banco externo  ?

Comment: Até onde eu conheço, apesar de ser possível acessar outra banco de dados via FDW (Foreign Data Wrapper) no padrão SQL/MED, não é possível definir uma constraint entre diferentes bancos de dados.

Comment: Já pesquisou sobre LINKED SERVER ? https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @EdvaldoLucena não, nunca tinha visto LINKED SERVER, já estou dando uma olhada no link, obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score -2):

SIm, é possível atraves do linkedserver. Onde você pega o Banco A e o Banco B (ipdobanco/Nome do banco no linkedserver) e monta a sua consulta

select * from BancoA.dbo.tabelaA;

Select * from BancoB.dbo.tabelaA;

Mais detalhes linkedserver: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15